# Pesquisa em 2 campos ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

[image: Código da pesquisa]Eae,

tenho dois campos em uma tabela mysql,  descricao e grau.

como faço para que quando eu pesquise tipo PALAVRA  e 4 ( sendo PALAVRA do campo descricao e 4 do campo grau? apareça um resultado?

PS.: tanto descricao como grau estão no modo text.

PS2.: se eu pesquisar separadamente ele acha resultado (tipo, se eu digitar só PALAVRA ele acha, e se eu pesquisar só 4 ele acha também)

Comment: Primeiro poste a query que está usando, para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre coloquei ai ^^

Comment: Um `AND` resolve, não? Tipo  `tal campo LIKE '%sua palavra%' AND tal campo LIKE '%outra palavra%'`, acho que é isso, não entendi muito bem sua pergunta

Comment: @WotonSampaio é assim, muitas vezes o que vao digitar nesse sistema está presente em mais de um campo, mas o query não mostra o resultado quando eu digito algo que está presente nos dois campos, usando o exemplo que eu coloquei na pergunta se eu digitar palavra 4, não mostra resultado, mesmo tendo palavra no campo descricao e 4 no campo grau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fazendo o explode e montando sua query:

```
//Separo a frase por espaço
$v = explode(" ", "palavra 4");

$query = 'SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE ';

foreach ($v as $key => $value) {
   $query .= "campo_1 LIKE '%" . $value . "%' OR campo_2 LIKE '%" . $value . "%' OR ";
}

//Retiro o último 'OR '
echo substr($query, 0, -3);
```

O exemplo imprime: `SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE campo_1 LIKE '%palavra%' OR campo_2 LIKE '%palavra%' OR campo_1 LIKE '%4%' OR campo_2 LIKE '%4%'`

Esse exemplo é bem genérico, mas com ele vc consegue entender como vc pode montar sua query de forma bem simples

Comment: Valeu cara, deu pra entender e funcionou aqui

Comment: @EduardoRodrigues de nada ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer fazer uma query que busque em dois campos ao mesmo tempo se alguma coisa esta em um campo ou no outro...se for isso e só usar OR.

se voce estiver querendo pesquisar duas palavras digitadas no mesmo input, voce tera que tratar elas primeiro. Nao sei muito de php, mas deve ter alguma função que separe uma string, tipo um split() onde voce passe como argumento um separador, esse separador pode ser um espaço, uma virgula ou um tab.

Comment: sim, você entendeu certo, já tentei com o OR, mas da o mesmo resultado. Se eu digitar só PALAVRA ele acha no campo descrição, se eu digitar só 4 ele acha no campo grau, mas se eu digitar PALAVRA 4 ele não acha em nenhum dos dois campos.

Comment: @EduardoRodrigues O Rodrigo está certo, vc deve usar um explode na vdd, split é pra java kkkkkk, pode usar um foreach pra fazer a query, vou mandar um exemplo numa resposta, fica mais organizado